# GitLab disable a stage if pipeline ran manually

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration

I have created a stage in GitLab to build a container only if Dockerfile in repository is modified, but it runs every time I run the pipeline manually, following is the code in `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

```
stages:
    - build_base_container
    - build

build_base_container:
  stage: build_base_container
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind

  script:
    - |
      docker login registry.gitlab.com -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
      docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE .      
      docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
      docker logout ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
  rules:
    - changes: 
      - dockerfile
```

This stage should only run if Dockerfile is modified not in any other condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a simple solution as mentioned below.

```
rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      changes:
        - dockerfile
      when: always
```

Now it run only if there is a push event which was exactly my requirement.

Comment: That's a great solution too!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known behavior as mentioned in the doc: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#ruleschanges

A manual pipeline is not a *push event*, which means your rule will always evaluate to true when running a new pipeline manually.

Maybe you can consider running this pipeline on a tag?

```
buld_base_container:
  only:
    refs:
      - tags
```

Or with the rules syntax:

```
buld_base_container:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v.+/'
      when: on_success
```

You can then add a tag to the commit you change the Dockerfile:

```
git tag v1.0.0
git push --tags
```

With a tag, you can also tag your image instead of using latest each time.

Hope it helps!